# How upload file to blob storage and reference it from cosmosdb document in attachment

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to CosmosDb and azure blob storage, as a requirement I need to reference a file uploaded to azure blob storage from a document in CosmosDb and use it in the attachment section to save the metadata.

I know the json metadata stucture should be like this:

```
{    
   "id":"image13d65101-90c4-4c2a-a423-fbf221c73233",  
   "contentType":"image/jpg",  
   "media":"www.bing.com",  
   "_rid":"rnYYAMVFUAUBAAAAAAAAAEC+LNM=",  
   "_ts":1408056025,  
   "_self":"dbs\/rnYYAA==\/colls\/rnYYAMVFUAU=\/docs\/rnYYAMVFUAUBAAAAAAAAAA==\/attachments\/rnYYAMVFUAUBAAAAAAAAAEC+LNM=",  
   "_etag":"00002a00-0000-0000-0000-53ed3ad90000"  
}
```

but how can I get a reference to the media property when uploading the file to azure blob storage, more accurately how do I upload a file from c# to azure blob storage and reference it by setting the url to the media property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample code from one of my application to upload to blob storage and then save the reference to the cosmosdb as a uri,

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImageAsync([FromBody] ImageUploadRequest imageRequest)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageRequest?.Base64))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var tokens = imageRequest.Base64.Split(',');
        var ctype = tokens[0].Replace("data:", "");
        var base64 = tokens[1];
        var content = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        // Upload photo to storage...
        var blobUri = await UploadImageToStorage(content);

        // Then create a Document in CosmosDb to notify our Function
        var identifier = await UploadDocument(blobUri, imageRequest.Name ?? "Bob");

        return Ok(identifier);
    }

    private async Task<Guid> UploadDocument(Uri uri, string imageName)
    {

        var endpoint = new Uri(_settings.ImageConfig.CosmosUri);
        var auth = _settings.ImageConfig.CosmosKey;
        var client = new DocumentClient(endpoint, auth);
        var identifier = Guid.NewGuid();

        await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database() { Id = dbName });
        await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(dbName),
            new DocumentCollection { Id = colName });

        await client.CreateDocumentAsync(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(dbName, colName),
            new ImageDocument
            {
                Id = identifier,
                IsApproved = null,
                PetName = petName,
                MediaUrl = uri.ToString(),
                Created = DateTime.UtcNow
            });

        return identifier;
    }

    private async Task<Uri> UploadImageToStorage(byte[] content)
    {
        var storageName = _settings.PetsConfig.BlobName;
        var auth = _settings.PetsConfig.BlobKey;
        var uploader = new PhotoUploader(storageName, auth);
        var blob = await uploader.UploadPetPhoto(content);
        return blob.Uri;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it helped a lot. Thank you @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 1):

> how do I upload a file from c# to azure blob storage and reference it
>   by setting the url to the media property.

You can refer to this article [Setting and retrieving metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata#setting-and-retrieving-metadata), you should get the blob again after uploading it.

Sample code like this:

```
        //the code to get the blob again after uploading.
        var blockblob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobname);

        //the code to set medadata.
        blockblob.FetchAttributes();
        blockblob.Metadata["media"] = "www.bing.com";
        blockblob.SetMetadata();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but it is not what I was looking for.