# Adding an Attachment to a Document - How To add any file type

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am using **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos** to perform **CRUD** in a C# Blazor app. I'm using the **CosmosClient** - Adding/Updating a simple Customer object. This all works fine.

I would like to add documents to the Customer 'record'. How do you do this? I can't find any good sample code or explainations.

The added document to the customer record could be a file type such as  DOC, PDF, PNG, BMP, JPG etc...  I'd like to support any file type.

I have an existing class that does the normal CRUD.. looks like this, How can I add Attachements as well,
Any help is appreciated.

*I do not want to save the document/attachment in separate BLOB, at this time.*

```
public class CosmosDbService : ICosmosDbService
    {
        private Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container _container;
        public CosmosDbService(
          CosmosClient dbClient,
          string databaseName,
          string containerName)
        {
            this._container = dbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
        }

        public async Task AddCustomerAsync(Customer cust)
        {
            await this._container.CreateItemAsync<Customer>(cust, new PartitionKey(fp.Id));
        }
        public async Task DeleteCustomerAsync(string id)
        {
            await this._container.DeleteItemAsync<Customer>(id, new PartitionKey(id));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Attachments are deprecated in Cosmos DB. You will need to store these in blob storage.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you do this and link it to a record

Comment: Use the code here and store the URI in a property for the record, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet-legacy#upload-blobs-to-a-container

Comment: How do you associate a Blob with Cosmos?  Use the file name?

Comment: Every blob has a URI. Insert that into Cosmos as part of the document. This answer may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996696/how-upload-file-to-blob-storage-and-reference-it-from-cosmosdb-document-in-attac